# REINFORCE implementation - should we multiply $G_t$ by $\gamma^t$?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policy-gradient

I think I see a contradiction between two blog posts, please help me decide if there's an error somewhere or how do these align:

[lilian weng](https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2018-02-19-rl-overview/#deadly-triad-issue) claims this: [image: lil]

while [wouter van heeswijk](https://towardsdatascience.com/policy-gradients-in-reinforcement-learning-explained-ecec7df94245) claims this: [[image: wouter]

who is right?

Comment: because for infinite horizon task you need a discount, or you will end up with infinite returns... the exponential decay solves this

Answer (score 0):

Well... it depends. If you define $\gamma=1$ (no discounting) then it is pointless and you can omit it from the formula. You have to define $\gamma$ for your problem, that is define if you wish to discount rewards from previous times or not.

Comment: thanks, but i don't think so - the discount goes into effect while calculating $G_t$

Comment: @ihadanny I don't see it, the first formula has $\gamma$ separate from $G$, while the second has no mention of $\gamma$ in the cumulative reward formula.